# Click event not generating on google maps here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple

Tags: google-maps

I was going through google maps API v3 and found out that click event is not working here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/event-simple . Is this a known issue?

Comment: It is working for me in Chrome. What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome only, on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

You can try zoom out, after click marker for:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    map.setZoom(8);
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
  });
```